# using windows shadow copy for folders, files

Tags: windows, backup, ntbackup, vss

it seems only R2 versions of W2k3 and W2k8 support folder, file level VSS backup. In regular Windows server editions only volumes could be backed up.
is there any links or doc to confirm this behavior?

> 2008R2 edition:   launch "windows
>   server backup", Choose "custom" backup ... "select items for backup"
>   Windows 2008 edition:  displays only volumes ....(C, D...)?

Answer (score 0):

Vss has been a part of windows since windows 2003 see [How Volume Shadow Copy Service Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785914(WS.10).aspx)
VSS is a volume shadow copy.  There is no "file level" volume shadow copy service.  VSS is used by many (including microsoft) backup software solutions in order to do file level backup.  In addition VSS is used to enable the previous versions feature.

Comment: Hi Jim, R2 versions allow you to choose "files, folders" during backup apart from volume. what could this be?
w2k3: ntbackup
w2k8: server backup
both use VSS services but they are more flexible in R2 versions to allow individual files/folders to be selected on a volume? any thoughts? thx in adv.

Comment: So you are really asking about ntbackup - not VSS.  It's a *volume* shadow copy.  I couldn't find much in the way of differences between r2 ntbackup and ntbackup under 2003 (windows server backup is different).  Can you elaborate on exactly what the difference is that you are seeing?

Comment: i am taliking about "windows backup" in 2008 server vs R2 editions. Choose "custom" backup option >> "select items for backup" appears in R2 version. But Srv 2008 displays only volumes (C, D...). Why is this?